# Problem with Terminal after changed permission to /usr/bin

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

I was trying to install rake and rspec using ruby gems.  I changed read permissions on /usr/bin

Now my terminal window looks like this:

login(388,0x7fff73cd5310) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fdb79c05290: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

[Process completed]

Comment: What did you change the permissions to, and did you do it recursively with the `-R` operator? Default permissions for `/usr/bin` should be 755. Changing the permissions may have blocked access to files that Terminal needs. You may have to drop into Recovery mode and try a permissions repair, or if you can get a Terminal session there, reset the permissions to 755.

Comment: I did use -R. How do I get into Recovery mode?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you changed the read permissions on `/usr/bin` recursively, trying to restore the proper permissions through Terminal will not work - too many items in there have unique permissions. The best plan of action to remedy this I have is as follows.

1. Open Disk Utility and run Repair Permissions on your disk. This may restore the proper permissions on the files in `/usr/bin`.
2. Reboot into Recovery mode (hold the R key down during boot) and run Disk Utility there  attempting the same Repair Permissions.
3. If you have a Time Machine backup, restore your system from a time prior to making the permissions change. This would be accessed through Recovery mode.

Takeaway from this is never change permissions recursively on a directory unless you specifically know what you're doing.